# Pentaho Role Intersection

Tags: pentaho, roles, mondrian

I am working with roles in mondrian schema and i would like to know if possible to make intersection of two declared roles.

I created these roles:

For product manager that has restriction on specific types of products

```
<Role name="product_manager">
    <SchemaGrant access="none">
      <CubeGrant cube="product" access="all">
          <HierarchyGrant hierarchy="product_group" rollupPolicy="partial" access="custom">
           <MemberGrant member="[product_group].[Wardrobes]" access="all">
           </MemberGrant>
          </HierarchyGrant>
        </CubeGrant>
    </SchemaGrant>
  </Role>
```

And financial manager that has restriction on specific country

```
<Role name="financial_manager">
        <SchemaGrant access="none">
          <CubeGrant cube="country" access="all">
              <HierarchyGrant hierarchy="country" rollupPolicy="partial" access="custom">
               <MemberGrant member="[country].[Germany]" access="all">
               </MemberGrant>
              </HierarchyGrant>
            </CubeGrant>
        </SchemaGrant>
      </Role>
```

My required result should be intersection of these two roles, i found that exist element **UNION**, but i found that it returns sum of both so the user can see all from both, it isn't my required solution.

```
<Role name="product_and_financial_manager_for_wardrobes_and_germany_resort">
    <Union>
        <RoleUsage roleName="product_manager" />
        <RoleUsage roleName="financial_manager" />
    </Union>
  </Role>
```

Something like this:

```
 <Role name="product_and_financial_manager_for_wardrobes_and_germany_resort">
        <Intersection>
            <RoleUsage roleName="product_manager" />
            <RoleUsage roleName="financial_manager" />
        </Intersection>
      </Role>
```

This is example on data:

**fact_product**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  id_fact_product   |  price    | id_dim_product_group  | id_dim_country
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1                  |   100     |   1                   |    1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2                  |    150    |   1                   |    2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3                  |    120    |   2                   |    2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4                  |    230    |   1                   |    2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**dim_product_group**

```
----------------------------------------------
| id_dim_product_group  |  section
----------------------------------------------
|  1                    |  Wardrobes
----------------------------------------------
|  2                    |  Tables
----------------------------------------------
```

**dim_country**

```
----------------------------------------------
| id_dim_country        |  country
----------------------------------------------
|  1                    |  Italy
----------------------------------------------
|  2                    |  Germany
----------------------------------------------
```

The result for Role **product_and_financial_manager_for_wardrobes_and_germany_resort** should be see data only in this range

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |  id_fact_product   |  price    | id_dim_product_group  | id_dim_country
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | 2                  |    150    |   1                   |    2
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | 4                  |    230    |   1                   |    2
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
    |  section           |  country  | 
    -----------------------------------
    |  Wardrobes         |  Germany  | 
    -----------------------------------
    | Wardrobes          |  Germany  | 
    -----------------------------------
```

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature in Mondrian. I suggest creating a ticket in the [Jira tracker](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/MONDRIAN).

Alternatively, you could [implement the Role interface](http://devdonkey.blogspot.ca/2012/09/programmatic-roles-in-mondrian.html) and pass it to your connection.